# Big O notation g(n) ∈ O(f(n)) =⇒ (g(n))^2 ∈ O((f(n))^2)

Tags: big-o

My question is, is this True.

g(n) ∈ O(f(n)) =⇒ (g(n))^2 ∈ O((f(n))^2)

At the long run it should be true, but i have one example (log n )^ 2 which is still in or less then  O(sqrt n)

Is there a way to proof this without the graph.

THX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is quite intuitive that, if a function `g` is less or equally fast than another function `f`, the square of `g` is less or equally fast than the square of `f`.

Formally:

- **Statement #1**. `g(n) ∈ O(f(n))` means that, for at least one choice of a constant `k > 0`, you can find a constant `a` such that the inequality `0 ≤ g(n) ≤ k f(n)` holds for all `n > a`.
- **Statement #2**. `g(n)^2 ∈ O(f(n)^2)` means that, for at least one choice of a constant `k > 0`, you can find a constant `a` such that the inequality `0 ≤ g(n)^2 ≤ k f(n)^2` holds for all `n > a`.

Since we want to prove that `g(n) ∈ O(f(n))` implies `g(n)^2 ∈ O(f(n)^2)`, we want to reach the statement #2 starting from the statement #1.

Let us take two constants `k` and `a` such that the statement #1 is satisfied.

First, notice that:

- `0 ≤ k f(n)` holds for all `n > a` (from hypotesis);
- ⇒ `0 ≤ f(n)` holds for all `n > a` (since `k > 0`). [**Result #1**]

Also notice that:

- `g(n) ≤ k f(n)` holds for all `n > a` (from hypotesis);
- ⇒ `g(n)^2 ≤ (k f(n))^2` holds for all `n > a` (since, from hypotesis and result #1, both `g(n)` and `f(n)` are non-negative for all `n > a`, so we can keep the `≤` sign);
- ⇒ `g(n)^2 ≤ k^2 f(n)^2` holds for all `n > a`. [**Result #2**]

From results #1 and #2, the statement #2 is satisfied.

Q.E.D.